# Scrapy is ignoring my logging settings and printing DEBUG

Tags: scrapy

I'm running Scrapy 1.3 spiders from a script and I followed the recommended practices

```
configure_logging({'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO'})
process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```

I also set the LOG_LEVEL at settings.py just in case

```
LOG_LEVEL = 'WARNING'
```

But Scrapy ignores it and is printing DEBUG on the log.
I don't define logging anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), I think you are mixing the `CrawlerRunner` example with the `CrawlerProcess` one. Here's the one for `CrawlerRunner`:

```
...    
configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(MySpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Contrary to `CrawlerProcess()` which needs to be passed some settings, like mentionned in the docs (example from docs including your `LOG_LEVEL` setting):

```
...
process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
    'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
})

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: For me, putting `LOG_LEVEL:WARNING` is still outputting all the logs including `DEBUG` and `INFO` why is this happening?